# Why does fmt round 0.5 rounded to 0, for zero decimals?

Tags: c++, fmt

I fully implemented the fmt library in my project. But the last bug I found was that values previously where rounded to the higher bound (0.5 -> 1), while they currently are rounded to their lower bound (0.5 -> 0).

When trying to find the cause, I found:

```
double halfd = 0.5;
std::string str = fmt::format("{:.0f}", halfd ); // result: "0"

float halff = 0.5f
std::string str = fmt::format("{:.0f}", halff ); // result: "0"
```

I also tried, if the compiler maybe stores 0.5 as 0.49999999999..., but I could not find the cause.

I work with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 with v140 compiler.

Does anybody know why fmt rounds 0.5 to 0, instead of 1. I previously used the standard printf library.

Comment: It advertizes [IEEE 764 rounding compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules)

Comment: Floris Jonkman Why do you think 1.0 is the correct result and not 0.0?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it is common in math to round up 0.5 to 1.0. He is asking why this is different with fmt, as he probably does not know about IEEE 754 rounding compliance.

Answer (score 2):

As commented on [this github issue](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2227) {fmt} uses [round to nearest even mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) which is the default rounding mode in IEEE 754. glibc's `printf` does the same by default: https://godbolt.org/z/jfor1cedo.